# How to form a CNF of following formula

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

We got an exercise to make a CNF out of the following formula: $$G = ((A \vee \neg B \vee C) \wedge (C \vee D)) \vee ((A \vee \neg C) \wedge (B \wedge D))$$ I've tried to make an equivalent equation but only had more questions afterwards. I hope you could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a CNF of $G$ we apply the distributive law. Let:
$$ M = A \vee \neg B \vee C$$
$$ N = C \vee D $$
$$ P = A \vee \neg C $$
$$ Q = B \wedge D $$

Then we have:

$$ G = (M \wedge N) \vee (P \wedge Q) $$

Now let $F = M \wedge N$ then applying the distributive law we get:

$$ G = (F \vee P) \wedge (F \vee Q)$$

And so we get:

$$ G = (P \vee M) \wedge (P \vee N) \wedge (F \vee Q) $$
$$ G = (P \vee M) \wedge (P \vee N) \wedge (Q \vee M) \wedge (Q \vee N) $$
$$ G = (P \vee M) \wedge (P \vee N) \wedge (M \vee B) \wedge (M \vee D) \wedge (N \vee B) \wedge (N \vee D)$$

Or:

$$ G = (A \vee \neg C \vee A \vee \neg B \vee C) \wedge (A \vee \neg C \vee C \vee D) \wedge (A \vee \neg B \vee C \vee B) \wedge (A \vee \neg B \vee C \vee D) \wedge (C \vee D \vee B) \wedge (C \vee D \vee D)$$

$$ G = (A \vee \neg B \vee C \vee D) \wedge (C \vee D \vee B) \wedge (C \vee D) $$

Which is in CNF. It can be verified that the final form given for $G$ is equivalent to the original by checking the truth table.

Comment: Your final expression for $G$ is in CNF but can be further simplified to $C \lor D$.

Comment: Yes this is true, but to arrive at $G = C \vee D$ one needs to do some additional work. But indeed $G = C \vee D$.

Comment: Thanks, I should probably start using placeholders in the future. Like in the post above, all seems to lead to $C \vee D$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
((A \lor \lnot B \lor C) \land (C \lor D)) \lor ((A \lor \lnot C) \land (B \land D))  \\
((A \lor \lnot B \lor C) \lor (A \lor \lnot C)) 
\land
((A \lor \lnot B \lor C) \lor (B \land D))
\land
((C \lor D) \lor (A \lor \lnot C)) 
\land
((C \lor D) \lor (B \land D)) \\
(A \lor \lnot B \lor \color{blue}{C \lor \lnot C}) 
\land
(A \lor \color{blue}{\lnot B} \lor C \color{blue}{\lor B})
\land
(A \lor \lnot B \lor C \lor D)
\land
(\color{blue}{C} \lor D \lor A \color{blue}{\lor \lnot C}) 
\land
(C \lor D \lor B)
\land
(C \lor D) \\
\color{blue}{T}
\land
\color{blue}{T}
\land
(A \lor \lnot B \lor C \lor D)
\land
\color{blue}{T}
\land
(C \lor D \lor B) 
\land
(C \lor D) \\
(A \lor \lnot B \lor \color{red}{C \lor D})
\land
(\color{red}{C \lor D} \lor B) 
\land
(\color{red}{C \lor D}) \\
\color{red}{C \lor D}
$$